# Media Exception is coming when trying to set the media time of the player

Tags: java-me

I am developing a video player . and i am also doing the streaming on this as :

```
String url="rtsp://v1.cache5.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQm8E_KpEOI9cxMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYLm0hv_ig5HRTww=/0/0/0/video.3gp";
VideoComponent videoComponent = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer(url);
Player player = (Player) videoComponent.getNativePeer();
player.realize();
player.prefetch();
player.start();
player.setMediaTime(9000000); // set the starting media time as 9 sec .
```

When i am setting the media time then it is throwing a media exception .
But when i show the video from resource folder then it works successfully .but when i do streaming then it throws an error . 

What can be solution for set the media time?

Answer (score 0):

rtsp stands for [Real Time Streaming Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol). According to the information on that page (PLAY session) you can use a Range request property.
Please, try it with an `HttpConnection` and call `setRequestProperty("Range", "9")` then create your `VideoComponent` using this stream instead of the `String` url.

Comment: Can you please share some snippet of code to make the http connection and get the input stream from the rtsp url ? i am getting error that "The requested protocol does not exists" when i am making the http connection.

Comment: My Bad... You will only get an HttpConnection for http protocol.

Comment: This exception was raised when calling Connector.open(url) right?

Comment: yes. this exception is coming in Connector.open(url) . Is there any other solution for that ?

Comment: Maybe from your VideoComponent class. Which API does it come from? What are the setter methods?